# How to find position of an object in an array in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, indexof

Here is my data:

```
{
  "bracketName": "Set Bracket Name",
  "bracketId": "tTzbUZ",
  "modID": "B11PTVjERm",
  "creationDate": 1503352813796,
  "teams": [{
      "name": "team 1",
    },
    {
      "name": "team 2",
    },
    {
      "name": "team 2",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the position of the `team`. Here is my code:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('brackets/' + data.bracket + '.json');
content = JSON.parse(content);  
content.teams.indexOf({"name": "team 2"});
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to do this. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content.teams.findIndex(team => team.name == 'team 2')
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works! I will make sure to mark it as the answer once it lets me (in 3 mins).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findIndex`. For example:

```
content.teams.findIndex(x => x.name=="team 2")
```

Comment: Thanks! I did see Danil comment this first, so he will get the answer, but thank you for answering so quickly!

Comment: I'd also Up vote it, but I'm not a high enough rank, sorry